# Is there a way to switch to a brush preset in Photoshop but keep the current brush size?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

I'd like to keep my current brush size when switching between Photoshop brush presets. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot keep the current brush size when switching to a brush preset that has a set size.

If the brush preset, that is switched to, has no size, then the current brush size will be retained.

Answer (score 1):

No. **Presets** are specific sizes.

You can change the **Brush Tip Shape** or other options and the size will be retained.

Comment: Wait, I figured it out. In CS6, when adding a brush preset, there's a checkbox for 'Capture brush size in preset'. Uncheck this, and you can switch to a brush preset, that has no brush size, and thus keep current brush size.

Comment: Yes if you *create* the preset yourself. Most stock preset have the size associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice workaround. When you import a new brush pack and you see a number below it, which indicates the brush size. Just click on the brush, then below click on the (+) button, create a new preset with exact the same brush but UNCHECK the "capture size". Now you got the same brush without a predetermined. Just erase the other one with the number. Done. [image]

[image]